# How to use react native Animated API with "%" positioning values?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-animated

I have an SVG `<line>`, which I want to animate using the `Animated API` of react native. In particular I want to animate the `x1` and `x2` properties of the line using relative positioning with `%`. However, I cannot combine my animated value with a `"%"` string. The following code results in `NaN%` or `[object Object]%`:

```
import { Animated } from 'react-native';
import { Svg, Line } from 'react-native-svg';
const AnimatedLine = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Line);

const myComponent = (props) => {
    //props.underlineX1 is something like: new Animated.Value(50)

    return(
        <Svg
            width="100%"
            height="100%">
            <AnimatedLine
                x1={`${props.underlineX1}%`} //or: x1={`${parseInt(props.underlineX1)}%`}
                x2={`${props.underlineX2}%`} //or: x2={`${parseInt(props.underlineX2)}%`}
                y1="40"
                y2="40"
                stroke={"green"}
                strokeWidth="2" />
        </Svg>
    )
}
```

What should I do to get values like `50%` when `props.underlineX1 = 50`?

EDIT:

When using the `JSON.stringify(props.underlineX1) + "%"` method I receive the correct values for initial positioning, but the animation will not be executed (which works fine if I use the absolute values directly without the combination of `"%"`).

Comment: Can you add the code you use to create your Animated values (`underlineX1` and `underlineX2`) as well as how you pass them via props to `myComponent`?

Comment: @MarekLisik You can just use it without passing from `props`. Just add two constants in `myComponent`: `const underlineX1 = new Animated.Value(50)` and `const underlineX2 = new Animated.Value(70)` and use them instead of the `props.underlineX1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to transform an `Animated.Value` to your percentage string, you will need to interpolate like so:

```js
const x1 = props.underlineX1.interpolate({
  inputRange: [0, 100],
  outputRange: ['0%', '100%'],
});
```

(note: this is assuming your animated values will be in the rage of 0-100)